# Ionic 2 native geolocation, no error thrown when location is turned off

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2

I m using `native geolocation` module of an Ionic 2. Following are the part of my code

```
import { Geolocation } from '@ionic-native/geolocation';

..
..
getLocation(){
        this.platform.ready().then(() => {

            this.geolocation.getCurrentPosition().then(pos => {
                console.warn("latitude = "+pos.coords.latitude);
                console.warn("longitude = "+pos.coords.longitude);
            }, (error) => {
                console.warn("Error in fetching location");

            });

    });
 }
```

I m testing app in an android phone. Everything works fine, except when the location is turned off, error is not thrown in the console. Can anybody tell me how to throw error if location service is turned off in the device??

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I have fixed myself

what I needed to do is -

```
this.geolocation.getCurrentPosition({timeout: 100})
```

I have to add timeout option as a parameter of a `getCurrentPosition` method.

According to Android Quirks section of plugin page:-

> If Geolocation service is turned off the onError callback is invoked
>   after timeout interval (if specified). If timeout parameter is not
>   specified then no callback is called.

For more details [Click Here](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-geolocation)

Infact I can also use `diagnostic` plugin to detect the location. [Check Here](http://ionicframework.com/docs/native/diagnostic/)